# BlockContent::load for addtoany_block returns null

Tags: 8, blocks

I am trying to load the "AddToAny Buttons" block of AddToAny module inside a controller. My idea is to render the block content as a part of the page. I have verified the block id of "AddToAny Buttons" block in the Addtoany module's block plugin file which is 'addtoany_block'. But BlockContent::load('addtoany_block') returns null. 
Could somebody help me identify where I'm going wrong?
Here is the code snippet

```
$block = \Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContent::load('addtoany_block');
$render = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->
getViewBuilder('block_content')->view($block);
```

Comment: `block_content` is the entity type of custom content blocks (the ones editorially created in the custom block library `/admin/structure/block/block-content`) - are you sure that your AddToAny block is one of those and not a code-generated block?

Comment: @Hudri it is a code-generated block. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1):

The `addtoany_block` is not a block content, but it's a plugin block.
So if you want to get the its build programmatically you should:
1. Get the block configuration (addtoany_block settings).
2. Create an instance of the block.
3. Get the build.

Try the following:

```
// Block manager.
$block_manager = \Drupal::service('plugin.manager.block');
// Load Block settings / Settings.
$addtoany_config = \Drupal::config('addtoany.settings')->getRawData();
/** @var \Drupal\addtoany\Plugin\Block\AddToAnyBlock $plugin_block */
$addtoany_block = $block_manager->createInstance('addtoany_block', $addtoany_config);
// Get Block build.
$build = $addtoany_block->build();
```

Comment: Thanks, @berramou. It worked for me.

Comment: i'm glad that helped, mark it as the right answer to help someone else.